# Why do I need to specify both a name and ng-model on input in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I was just wondering why I have to specify both `name` and `ng-model` on an input element in a form to be able to actually use it correctly.
For example, with the following:

```
  <form name='test'>
      <div>
          <input type='radio' 
              value='create-new'
              ng-model='toggle'
              required />

          <input type='radio' 
              value='use-existing'
              ng-model='toggle'
              required />
      </div>
      <div ng-switch='test.$invalid'>
          <div ng-switch-when='true'>Invalid!</div>
          <div ng-switch-when='false'>Valid!</div>
      </div>
  </form>
```

I would get the output `Invalid!` when I don't select a radio button - this is correct behaviour. However, the downside is that the only way I can access this model is through `$scope.toggle` - the element itself will not be referencable by name inside of `$scope.test` (the form container). `$scope.test` *will* contain the validation rules for `toggle`, but it will *not* have any way of letting you know that those validation rules are belonging to `toggle` as the name is not present.

If we were to switch it around put a name attribute on the input:

```
  <form name='test'>
      <div>
          <input type='radio' 
              value='create-new'
              name='toggle'
              required />

          <input type='radio' 
              value='use-existing'
              name='toggle'
              required />
      </div>
      <div ng-switch='test.$invalid'>
          <div ng-switch-when='true'>Invalid!</div>
          <div ng-switch-when='false'>Valid!</div>
      </div>
  </form>
```

Then our `ng-switch` at the bottom will always show Valid, even though I've mentioned that the input itself is required. In addition, `toggle` now shows up inside of `$scope.test`, so I can check the validity of `$scope.test.toggle` elsewhere (without requiring an inline attribute on that element).

If I combine both approaches and use both `name` and `ng-model`, then both results are combined and I get the result I would have expected  - I can see `$scope.test.toggle` *and* the model itself is validating correctly.

My question is why is this the appropriate behaviour? It seems different to, say, `jquery.validate.unobtrusive`, where the `name` attribute is the bit that intrinsically ties the validation rules to the element.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`name` attribute is used for angular validation, `ng-model` for binding,

if you are not going to validate with angular you don’t have to use `name`

if you are not binding then don’t use `ng-model`

both are necessary if you need to validate in client side with angular and need binding